# Soundcloud API returns empty

Tags: api, return, soundcloud

Thanks in advance for the help.

So while developing an application, I need API data and I retrieve JSON objects. Not a big deal, but with one certain account it doesn't work.

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/257255126?client_id=CLIENT_ID_HERE

The ID `257255126` is a track from this profile: https://soundcloud.com/discoverysounds1/.

Every track from this profile returns empty from the API while the same API link works if I insert a track ID from **any** other profile.

I've already notified the owner of the problem and he hasn't done anything weird or disabled API access if that's even possible.

What could be the problem here?

Thanks,

Jordan

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with a website I am developing using the API.

If I add one of the tracks to an existing playlist that I have created to test certain functionality, the track does not appear in the playist when retrieved via the /me/playlists endpoint.

When I load the playlist into the soundcloud widget, the track is visible and unrestricted (as in full duration and not a 30 second preview).

I am seeing similar behaviour with tracks that are marked as "soundcloud go" not being visible in the playlist tracks from the /me/playlists endpoint, but available via the widget when the playlist is loaded (albeit only a 30 second preview in their case).

Those items are identifiable as having a "SUB_HIGH_TIER" monetization_model

[image]

The track I loaded from your example

[image]

There seem to be various issues with the API right now related to the implementation of "soundcloud go"

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure it out. Guess there's not much I can do but wait for soundcloud themselves to fix this. You know of any way to notify them?